# Какие используете плагины для профилирования в Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, поиск-библиотек, профилирование

Нужно выявлять узкие места в коде (в основном Python) , какие функции дольше всего работают, чаще вызываются, сколько жрут памяти и процессора, желательно с графиками

Answer (score 0):

cProfile, если говорить о библиотеках. Я ограничиваюсь сохранением его вывода в файл. И там смотрю.